# A list variable is used in a function when it seems empty

Tags: python, frappe

I'm creating a [Frappe App](https://github.com/frappe/frappe), similar (**working**) functionality exists so I'm trying to reuse this code. I can't find the actual assignment for the `lst` variable anywhere in this python document (using search, its a local variable for this function). So far it seems like an empty list at declaration, however, its treated as if it contains a value.

Or am I just misunderstanding the code itself?

first, `lst` is declared as a list (empty)

```
lst = []
```

The it is assigned to reconciled_entry (still empty)

```
reconciled_entry = lst
```

Then it is used as follows:  (still empty)

```
if lst:
        reconcile_against_document(lst)
```

**The function reconcile_against_document function expects an actual list:**

***Is it still empty???***

```
def reconcile_against_document(args):
    """
        Cancel JV, Update against document, split if required and resubmit jv
    """
    for d in args:

        check_if_advance_entry_modified(d)
        validate_allocated_amount(d)

        # cancel advance entry
        doc = frappe.get_doc(d.voucher_type, d.voucher_no)

        doc.make_gl_entries(cancel=1, adv_adj=1)
...
```

**Main function:**

```
def reconcile(self, args):
        for e in self.get('payments'):
            e.invoice_type = None
            if e.invoice_number and " | " in e.invoice_number:
                e.invoice_type, e.invoice_number = e.invoice_number.split(" | ")

        self.get_invoice_entries()
        self.validate_invoice()
        dr_or_cr = ("credit_in_account_currency"
            if erpnext.get_party_account_type(self.party_type) == 'Receivable' else "debit_in_account_currency")

        lst = []
        dr_or_cr_notes = []
        for e in self.get('payments'):
            reconciled_entry = []
            if e.invoice_number and e.allocated_amount:
                if e.reference_type in ['Sales Invoice', 'Purchase Invoice']:
                    reconciled_entry = dr_or_cr_notes
                else:
                    reconciled_entry = lst

                reconciled_entry.append(self.get_payment_details(e, dr_or_cr))

        if lst:
            reconcile_against_document(lst)

        if dr_or_cr_notes:
            reconcile_dr_cr_note(dr_or_cr_notes)

        msgprint(_("Successfully Reconciled"))
        self.get_unreconciled_entries()
```

Comment: `if lst:` will not succeed if the list is empty. So you'll only call the function with a non-empty list.

Comment: I wonder when it is assigned

Comment: It's never assigned except for when it's initialized to the empty list. So the code makes no sense.

Comment: It might be left over from an earlier version that updated the variable.

Comment: Thats a possibility Barmer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got some help through email.

Python object assignment is funny. From my understanding, when `lst` (object) is assigned to another variable (`new_lst` which also becomes an object variable), what happens to one object variable affects the other

[image: python demo screenshot]

```
>>> lst = []
>>> new_lst = lst
>>> new_lst.append('funny python')
>>> lst
['funny python']
>>> lst.append('not funny python')
>>> new_lst
['funny python', 'not funny python']
>>> lst
['funny python', 'not funny python']
```